# Activity doesnt show up

Tags: android, themes

i want to make a Login page for the app. however the activity is not showing its only a blank page with a single title bar with a app name that is there. i tried different themes but the problem remains the same.

here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="variofitness.com.schedulekeeper">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/img_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

And Here is my styles file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/lightBlue</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">?android:textAppearanceLarge</item>

</style>


<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Parent theme sets colorControlNormal to textColorPrimary. -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/lightBlue</item>
</style>



</resources>
```

Here is my java code..

```
package variofitness.com.schedulekeeper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by vinod on 1/29/16.
 */
  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

EditText edtUserName,edt_password;

TextInputLayout input_application_password,input_application_userName;
TextView txt_Forgot_Password;
Button btn_login,btn_request_For_signUp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_login);
    initializeComponents();
}

private void initializeComponents() {
    input_application_password = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.input_application_password);
    input_application_userName = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.input_application_userName);

    edtUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
    edt_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

    txt_Forgot_Password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Forgot_Password);

    btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btn_request_For_signUp =     (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_request_For_signUp);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.txt_Forgot_Password:

            break;

        case R.id.btn_login:

            break;

        case R.id.btn_request_For_signUp:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
}
```

can anyone help me to tell me what i am missing?

Comment: @RRR i have added my java code.. i am not doing anything but initializing views for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
```

Replace this piece of code with

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Well thank you :), but looking closely at code i figured that out and solved it.. and Yeah the error was only that what you have shown :)